# How to type in an adb command?

Tags: android, adb

noob here. I just got lollipop and rooted my nexus device. I wanted to make some changes such as showing the battery percentage at all times using the following command:

`adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:status_bar_show_battery_percent --bind value:i:1`

How/where do I type this command in? I rooted using CF-Auto-Root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADB Shell commands are entered in the Terminal of the system you have your Android device connected to (via USB) and should have enabled the developer mode on that device. If you don't already know how to do so, please refer to the following link:

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Look under "Enabling On-Device Developer options".

There are many resources available that would help you out in learning ADB shell commands. I would recommend that you start with these links (plus a lot more):

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1WcYXpFCjFs

Answer (score 0):

download the adb/fastboot combination:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790

Add ADB to your path variable. (For easier access to adb);

On Windows look here for a good tutorial:
http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/

On linux I recommend installing adb through `apt-get install android-tools-adb`

Now check if you have installed it correctly by running command (CMD in Windows; Terminal in Linux):
`adb devices`
Make sure your device is connected and drivers (Windows only) are installed for the above step!
If your device is listed. You can now run your command stated jn your question!!

Good luck adb'ing ;-)
Edit:
Was in the middle of writing this when you got the above answer.